Every K3 surface is deformation equivalent to a smooth quartic in $\mathbb{P}^3$: how to conclude in hyperelliptic case
I'm currently studying the proof of the fact that every two K3 surfaces are deformation equivalent; in particular, we show that every K3 surface is deformation equivalent to a smooth quartic in $\mathbb{P}^3$. The proof I'm reading is by Le Poties in Exp. VI of Geometrie des surfaces K3: modules et periodes. I got to the point where I want to prove the following

Let $X$ be a K3 surfaces, whose Picard group is generated by some bundle $L$ such that $(L.L)=4$. Then $L$ is isomorphic to a quartic in $\mathbb{P}^3$.

The proof of this fact is based on the existance of a finite morphism induced by $L$
$$\varphi_L: X \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}(H^0(X,L)^\vee),$$
such that $\varphi_L^*(\mathcal{O}(1))\simeq L$. We only have two possibilities now: if $\varphi_L$ has degree $1$, then $X$ is mapped birationally into a quartic in $\mathbb{P}^3$ and we're done. I have some doubts about the hyperelliptic case ($\operatorname{deg}(\varphi_L)=2$). Now $\varphi_L(X)$ is an irreducible quadric surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3$. If $X':=\varphi_L(X)$ is smooth, then $X' \simeq \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ and $\operatorname{Pic}(X)=\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ generated by $\mathcal{O}(1,0)$ and $\mathcal{O}(0,1)$. Now
Question 1: why does this contradict the fact that $\operatorname{Pic}(X)$ is generated by $L$?
If $X':=\varphi_L(X)$ is not smooth, then I should see that $\mathcal{O}(1)|_{X'}$ has a square root as a Weil divisor, and I should get a contradiction by pulling it back as a square root of $L$. Question 2: how do I prove that $\mathcal{O}(1)|_{X'}$ has a square root?

Question 1: The line bundle $\mathcal{O}(1,1)$ pulls back to $L$ (this is because of how $\phi_L$ is defined). Therefore, if we let $A = \phi_L^* \mathcal{O}(1,0)$ and $B = \phi_L^* \mathcal{O}(0,1)$, then $L = A \otimes B$. But $A$ and $B$ are both non-zero effective line bundles so this contradicts the fact that Pic(X) = $\mathbb{Z}L$.
Question 2: Up to isomorphism, there are only 3 different singular quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^3$ (see Hartshorne I Ex. 5.12a).
There is the double plane $x^2 = 0$. This one cannot be the image because it is non-reduced.
There is two disjoint planes $xy = 0$. This cannot happen because it is reducible.
There is the quadric cone $z^2 = xy$. In this case, the ruling of the cone $D = ( z=0,x=0)$ is a Weil divisor that is a square root of $\mathcal{O}(1)_{|X'}$. This is because if we look at the Cartier divisor defined by $x=0$, we see from the equation for $X'$ that $z^2 = 0$, so $(x=0) = 2D$.
